# Using Android AFreeChart to save a line graph to a png or jpeg file

Tags: java, android, png, jpeg, jfreechart

I am using aFreeChart for Android. The reason for this is I started using JFreeChart before realising that this was not compatable with Android.

I am looking for an aFreeChart alternative to the below JFreeChart method:

```
ChartUtilities.saveChartAsJPEG(lineChart, lineChartObject, width, height);
```

My code for the line chart construction is as follows:

```
DefaultCategoryDataset line_chart = new DefaultCategoryDataset();

line_chart.addValue(load[23], "load profile", "0");
line_chart.addValue(load[0], "load profile", "1");
line_chart.addValue(load[1], "load profile", "2");
line_chart.addValue(load[2], "load profile", "3");
line_chart.addValue(load[3], "load profile", "4");
line_chart.addValue(load[4], "load profile", "5");
line_chart.addValue(load[5], "load profile", "6");
line_chart.addValue(load[6], "load profile", "7");
line_chart.addValue(load[7], "load profile", "8");
line_chart.addValue(load[8], "load profile", "9");
line_chart.addValue(load[9], "load profile", "10");
line_chart.addValue(load[10], "load profile", "11");
line_chart.addValue(load[11], "load profile", "12");
line_chart.addValue(load[12], "load profile", "13");
line_chart.addValue(load[13], "load profile", "14");
line_chart.addValue(load[14], "load profile", "15");
line_chart.addValue(load[15], "load profile", "16");
line_chart.addValue(load[16], "load profile", "17");
line_chart.addValue(load[17], "load profile", "18");
line_chart.addValue(load[18], "load profile", "19");
line_chart.addValue(load[19], "load profile", "20");
line_chart.addValue(load[20], "load profile", "21");
line_chart.addValue(load[21], "load profile", "22");
line_chart.addValue(load[22], "load profile", "23");

AFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createLineChart(
        "Load Profile over 24hrs", // Title
        "Time (Hrs)", // x-axis Label
        "Power (kVA)", // y-axis Label
        line_chart, // Dataset
        PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, // Plot Orientation
        true, // Show Legend
        true, // Use tooltips
        false // Configure chart to generate URLs?
);
```

Any ideas of how to save this to a jpg/jpeg/png file would be extremely helpful! I need to save as an image file as I need to embed it in a pdf at a later stage.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of *AFreeChart* I started using *MPAndroidChart* (which can be found at https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart). This is a great alternative as it lets you create charts and save them to image files (jpeg or png) with ease. I definitely recommend using it!